# threeJS procedural plane vertices not aligning

Tags: javascript, three.js, vertices, procedural-generation, simplex-noise

I'm using threeJS combined with a Simplex noise algorithm to generate a tile system of 50x50 planes. At the moment, I'm looping through x+y and adding each plane. I then use the Simplex noise algorithm to calculate the four vertices z position of the plane.

I am using the current x/y as the top left vertice ([0]), and the rest you can see below in the function that generates the tiles initially:

```
        PerlinSimplex.noiseDetail(4,0.5);

        x=0;
        y=0;

        while (x<32) {
            while (y<32) {
                l=(x*tilesize)+(tilesize/2);
                t=(y*tilesize)+(tilesize/2);
                //fScl= .07;
                fScl= 1;
                xx=x*fScl;
                yy=y*fScl;

                tl=Math.floor((PerlinSimplex.noise(xx,yy))*100);
                bl=Math.floor((PerlinSimplex.noise(xx,yy-1))*100);
                br=Math.floor((PerlinSimplex.noise(xx+1,yy-1))*100);
                tr=Math.floor((PerlinSimplex.noise(xx+1,yy))*100);

                addTile(t,l,tl,tr,bl,br);
                y++;
            }
            y=0;
            x++;
        }
```

Ok so thats the loop, then the addTile function:

```
    function addTile(x,y,tl,tr,bl,br) {

        var geo=new THREE.PlaneGeometry(tilesize, tilesize);
        geo.dynamic = true;

        geos.push(geo);

        var plane = new THREE.Mesh(geo, col);
        plane.overdraw = true;

        plane.geometry.vertices[0].z=tl;
        plane.geometry.vertices[1].z=tr;
        plane.geometry.vertices[2].z=bl;
        plane.geometry.vertices[3].z=br;


        plane.geometry.computeFaceNormals();
        plane.geometry.computeVertexNormals();    
        plane.geometry.__dirtyNormals = true;

        plane.position.x=x;
        plane.position.y=y;
        plane.position.z=0;

        scene.add(plane);

        planes.push(plane);

        plane.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;

        // changes to the normals
        plane.geometry.normalsNeedUpdate = true;

    }
```

(Quick note, I realised I think I don't need to have a new geometry for each plane)

Ok and here is the result:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/as7hb.jpg

As you can see, the vertices don't line up. I've tried quite a few things, but am totally stumped right now. I'm pretty sure I have the correct vertices being set as TL,TR, etc. Can you spot why the vertices aren't lining up?

Thankyou :)
Jack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it turns out I was passing t and l into the function the wrong way around. Doh!

:)